# How to base64 encode an image using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, base64, python-imaging-library

I have a stream of data that comes from a device and I need to convert it into a jpeg and then base64 encode it to transfer it over the network.

My Python 2.7 code so far looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import io

image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(self.imagebuffer)) # Image buffer contains the image data from the device.
image.save("test.jpg") # Writes the image to the disk in jpeg format
image.show() # Opens the image using the OS image view
```

I can see I have the image I want and can save it to the disk in jpeg format.

What I don't understand is if I can base64 encode the image from the `image` object or if I need to write it to the disk first. I would like to avoid writing it if possible.

The 2nd question I have is what is `PIL` doing in this process? Is it taking the data and putting the required special codes into the file to make it a jpeg file? I think the answer tot his is *yes* as I can change the file extension to `.bmp` and the correct file is written on the disk.

So in summary, is it possible to get a base64 encoded version of my jpeg file from the `image` object without writing it to disk first?

Comment: How exactly are you receiving this data from network, socket, urllib etc?

Comment: Comes from a UDP socket.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this code**

**Image base64 encoded format**

**Python code:**

```
import os
import base64

image = 'test.jpg'

encoded_string = ""
with open(image, "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    file = encoded_string
```

Answer (score 2):

This code does the job:

```
from PIL import Image
import io
import base64
import cStringIO

image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imagebuffer))
encodingbuffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
image.save(encodingbuffer, format="JPEG")
encodedimage = base64.b64encode(encodingbuffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: Does that touch the disk, before bs64?

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the img in a buffer - doesn't touch disk
2. regex for jpeg headers and footers - fault tolerance ( Header:  FF D8 FF, Footer: FF D9)
3. base64 the data
4. flush to file

Comment: Could really do with some code when you get the time. Thanks.

Comment: OK, self.imagebuffer contains the image data right?

Answer (score 0):

I`m working with .dwg file and Python 2.7, this works for me:

```
import os
import base64

# Open the file
infile = open(input_file, 'r')
# 'r' says we are opening the file to read, infile is the opened file object that we will read from
# encode file to base64
base64EncodedStr = base64.b64encode(infile.read())
```

Answer (score -1):

**Please try this to base64 encode an image using python**

```py
import base64

with open("test.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    print(encoded_string)
```

**OR**

```py
import base64

image = open('test.jpeg', 'rb')
image_read = image.read()
image_encode = base64.b64encode(image_read)
print(image_encode)
```